# wait after call command minecraft

Tags: java, batch, minecraft

I'm trying to create a batch file for a friend because he has some problems on minecraft.
He needs to launch minecraft 80 times without closing java error...
I have 2 batches, one with a while, and an other one executing java command for launching minecraft.

```
::Launcher.bat
title Script Minecraft
set tour=10
set tour2=tour

:boucle
set /a tour=tour-1
call "D:\thepath\Minecraft2.bat"
if %tour%==0 goto suite
goto boucle

:suite
wait javaw.exe

:boucle2
set /a tour2=tour2-1
taskkill /F /IM "javaw.exe"
if %tour2%==0 goto fin
goto boucle2

:fin
echo Appuyez sur une touche pour quitter...
pause >nul
```

and the other one

```
::Minecraft2.bat
@echo off
java -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -cp "D:\thepath\Minecraft.exe" net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

My problem is that when it calls the second batch, it's waiting for closure of the window but we must leave them opened !

If someone has already encountered this problem, I'd be grateful.

Thanks

PS: If my english is bad, it's because I'm french ;)

Answer (score 0):

just use an .vbs file (in notepad: save as all -> invisible minecraft start.vbs) :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\minecraft.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

and make an batchfile you want to call : minecraft.bat

```
START "minecraft" /high /wait "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\jinput.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl_util.jar" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft <username> <password>
```

of course, change  to the username and  to password

save these 2 in C:\ and make an link from the invisible mminecraft start to your desktop.
that's all...

this will help you, but your friend **has** to update java from [java.com](http://java.com/)

ps. if MY english is bad, i am dutch...